# Finding logs for Azure ServiceBus User Errors

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureservicebus

I see on the Metrics for my ServiceBus that there are a large number of user errors, but I can't find any logs telling me what those errors are.  They are not showing up in my AppInsights for the Azure Functions that read and write to this bus.  What am I missing?  Logging portion of my hosts.json looks like this:

```
"logging": {
   "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Warning",
      "Function": "Trace"
   }
},
```

Comment: where did you search the error message in Application insights?

Comment: In addition to Ivan's question, it would also be helpful to know if you have any custom logging in addition to the hosts.json and what language/host you are running on. Final question is if you are calling Service Bus via bindings or inside your own code.

Comment: @IvanYang I searched in the 'Search' tab and in the Log Analytics section.



    SamaraSoucy-MSFT C#, I believe Azure Functions V2.  Yes we have custom logging, but they are not showing these exceptions.  We interact with ServiceBus via bindings.  I'm really wondering why we can't just hook up AI to the ServiceBus directly if ServiceBus is taking metrics on failures already.

Comment: You can setup Service Bus to log the details to Log Analytics and union the data between the two workspaces, though in my experience the logs from Functions are going to be more helpful. Errors in the host process, in this case the bindings, are a bit trickier as they don't show up currently in the individual function run, but they should be showing up in the exceptions table in App Insights. There is some logging in app services itself, which you can get to at https://{app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole. If the error isn't making it to App Insights it may be there.