# How to browse user errors in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have 2k user errors depicted on the chart for Service Bus queue in azure portal however I cannot browse these errors to get to know their type or error message. Is there any tool or any other way to see it?

When these errors accumulating I see that outgoing messages chart is increasing and there are two times more messages than incoming.

I am sending messages to queue thanks to org.amqphub.spring:amqp-10-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically User errors are the number of request which are not processed due to user errors on a specific period.
There are two types of errors are defined as [user errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference#metrics) :

. Client-Side errors(In HTTP that would be 400 errors).
. Errors that occur while processing messages, such as  [MessageLockLostException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.messagelocklostexception).

Please refer the below links for further details:

[On how to Convert monitoring data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collection#convert-monitoring-data) for [end-to end Tracing & diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2).  & please find the similar [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63288181/finding-logs-for-azure-servicebus-user-errors) .